# convert pandas dataframe value to scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scalar

How do I convert a pandas data frame with 1 row, 1 column into a scalar value?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1': 1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: You're initialising the dataframe incorrectly. Did you mean; `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1]})`?

Comment: For this dataframe, just use `item`: `df.iloc[0].item()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) to access scalar elements specifying the location by integer (i.e. `0,0` for the top left element, as opposed to [at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) which would take the row and columns *labels* rather than integer index).

So if you only have one element in your dataframe, `df.iat[0,0]` will get it for you.

```
In [139]: import pandas as pd
In [140]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1], columns=['col1'])
In [141]: df.iat[0,0]
Out[141]: 1
In [143]: df
Out[143]: 
   col1
0     1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1], columns=['col1'])
df.squeeze()
```